# How can I extract a 'const' that depends on a map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, constants

I have animations in my component that follow the same style, like this:

```
{actions.map((action, i) => (
    <Component style={{ animation: `fade-animation 12s linear ${i * 3}s infinite` }}>{action}</Component>
))}

{figures.map((figure, i) => (
    <Component style={{ animation: `fade-animation 12s linear ${i * 3}s infinite` }}>{figure}</Component>
))}
```

The value `fade-animation 12s linear ${i * 3}s infinite` it's being repeated in multiple places.

How can I extract this into a *const*?

I tried:

```
const fadeAnimation = `fade-animation 12s linear ${i * 3}s infinite`;
```

But as the `i` depends on the map, it causes an error.

Can I extract this even with the `i`?

Comment: No, but you can extract it into a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const fadeAnimation = (time) => `fade-animation 12s linear ${time * 3}s infinite`;
```

Use it like this:

```
{figures.map((figure, i) => (
    <Component style={{ animation: fadeAnimation(i) }}>{figure}</Component>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Things to try:

This follows the [Inversion of Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) style.

```js
const fadeAnimation = duration => `fade-animation 12s linear ${duration}s infinite`;

{figures.map((figure, i) => (
    <Component style={{ animation: fadeAnimation(3 * i) }}>{figure}</Component>
))}
```

This follows [Default Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_(computer_programming)) style.

```js
const fadeAnimation = "fade-animation 12s linear infinite";

{figures.map((figure, i) => (
    <Component style={{ animation: `${fadeAnimation} ${i * 3}s` }}>{figure}</Component>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const fadeAnimation = (i) => `fade-animation 12s linear ${i * 3}s infinite`;
```

usage:

```
{figures.map((figure, i) => (
  <Component style={{ animation: fadeAnimation(i) }}>{figure}</Component>
))}
```

Comment: How does this improve on each of the older answers?

Comment: I answered in the same time as others

Comment: (I relied on *Sorted by: Date created*.)